# Shrink Text in Textbox without Wrap

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted textbox under insert --> shapes----> Textbox. now I want to resize textbox font if text-overflow textbox. I tried the following codes.

```
With Selection
If .TextFrame.HorizontalOverflow = msoTrue Then
Do
.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
Loop Until .TextFrame.HorizontalOverflow = msoFalse
End If

End with
```

ps: its Barcode font. so if it gets wrap then it's not readable by a barcode reader. so I want to shrink it.
But no success.

Thanks

Comment: In Excel, the Selection object is a range. It can't include a TextBox which is an ActiveX or MSForms control. The TextFrame object belongs to a Shape and its HorizontalOverFlow property can be set to truncate text. It can't be used to find out if the text overflows. To the best of my knowledge there is no way the various AutoFit options VBA offers can be beaten with any reasonable or unreasonable amount of coding.

Comment: hope if anybody has any workaround to this.

Comment: If the barcode will never be longer than a certain length you could consider sizing the width of your textbox by default to that length. It just means you might have some 'white space' if there are shorter barcodes.

Comment: In the VBA IDE place the cursor on the keyword HorizontalOverflow, press F1 and read the help page that comes up.  You may find that HorizontalOverflow is not what you think it is.

Comment: If your text box can hold 25 characters of the normal size then it should be 20% larger if there are actually 30 characters in a string the user entered. You would need to try out whether reducing the font size by 20% would have a similar effect. This method will never be 100% accurate because most fonts we use are proportional, meaning an i takes less space than a w but you will achieve an approximation that is better than doing nothing.

Comment: @Samuel Everson barcode width can be between 1 to 39 character .its barcode code 39 font. I can't use white space as user will need to align it with other textboxes.

Comment: @freeflow I know that my used property may not be available with VBA but I just used to let you know that what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Variatus may you are correct. but at list by reducing font size I expect it to get resized in the same proportion.

Answer (score 1):

The code below seems to achieve what you are looking for for standard text.  Maybe you can extract the principle and use it with your barcode style.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AdjustTextInTextBox()

    Dim myWs As Worksheet
    Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    myWs.Shapes.AddShape msoTextBox, 100, 100, 250, 50

    Dim myShape As Shape
    Set myShape = myWs.Shapes.Item(1)
    myShape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText

    Dim myHeight As Long
    myHeight = myShape.Height

    myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hello world its a really really really nice day"

    Do While myShape.Height > myHeight

        myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```